# How to get a value from a pandas core series?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df` in which are the timezones for particular ip numbers:

```
ip1         ip2           timezone
0           16777215          0
16777216    16777471       +10:00
16777472    16778239       +08:00
16778240    16779263       +11:00
16779264    16781311       +08:00
16781312    16785407       +09:00
...
```

The first row is valid for the ip numbers from 0 to 16777215, the second from 16777216 to 16777471 an so on.
Now, I go through a folder an want to know the timezone for every file (after I calculate the `ip_number` of the file).
I use:

```
time=df.loc[(df['ip1'] <= ip_number) & (ip_number <= df['ip2']), 'timezone']
```

and become my expected output:

```
1192    +05:30
Name: timezone, dtype: object
```

But this is panda core series series and I just want to have "+5:30".
How do I become this? Or is there another way instead of `df.loc[...]`to become directly the value of the column `timezone`in `df`?

Comment: Did my answer on the other question not work?

Comment: I don't really get it.. this method was much easier for me but I need help with this last step

Comment: This only works with *one* ip_number. If you want the values, do `time.values[0]`.

Answer (score 8):

just list it

```
list(time)
```

if you are excepting only one value

```
list(time)[0]
```

or you can make it earlier:

```
#for numpy array
time=df.loc[(df['ip1'] <= ip_number) & (ip_number <= df['ip2']), 'timezone'].values

#for list
time=list(df.loc[(df['ip1'] <= ip_number) & (ip_number <= df['ip2']), 'timezone'].values)
```

Answer (score 4):

To pull the only value out of a Series of size 1, use the [`Series.item()` method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.item.html):

```
time = df.loc[(df['ip1'] <= ip_number) & (ip_number <= df['ip2']), 'timezone'].item()
```

Note that this raises a `ValueError` if the Series contains more than one item.

---

Usually pulling single values out of a Series is an anti-pattern. NumPy/Pandas
is built around the idea that applying vectorized functions to large arrays is
going to be much much faster than using a Python loop that processes single
values one at a time.

Given your `df` and a list of IP numbers, here is a way to find the 
corresponding timezone offsets for *all* the IP numbers with just one call to [`pd.merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html).

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'ip1': [0, 16777216, 16777472, 16778240, 16779264, 16781312],
                   'ip2': [16777215, 16777471, 16778239, 16779263, 16781311, 16785407],
                   'timezone': ['0', '+10:00', '+08:00', '+11:00', '+08:00', '+09:00']})

df1 = df.melt(id_vars=['timezone'], value_name='ip').sort_values(by='ip').drop('variable', axis=1)
ip_nums = [16777473, 16777471, 16778238, 16785406]
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ip':ip_nums}).sort_values(by='ip')
result = pd.merge_asof(df2, df1)
print(result)
```

yields

```
         ip timezone
0  16777471   +10:00
1  16777473   +08:00
2  16778238   +08:00
3  16785406   +09:00
```

Ideally, your next step would be to apply more NumPy/Pandas vectorized functions
to process the whole DataFrame at once. But if you must, you could iterate
through the `result` DataFrame row-by-row. Still, your code will look a little bit cleaner
since you'll be able to read off ip and corresponding offset easily (and without calling `.item()`).

```
for row in result.itertuples():
    print('{} --> {}'.format(row.ip, row.timezone))
# 16777471 --> +10:00
# 16777473 --> +08:00
# 16778238 --> +08:00
# 16785406 --> +09:00
```